# Ubuntu, Qt5. Не собирается проект с opengl

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, qt5

Я новичок в Qt5, хочу написать простенькую прогу с интерактивной 3D графикой. Создаю приложение Qt Widgets, в нём по мануалу делаю `QT += opengl` в .pro,  `#include<QtOpenGL>` в .h, и всё, даже никакого кода не пишу больше, а при сборке начинается:

```
/opt/qtsdk/5.5/gcc/include/QtGui/qopenglext.h:117: ошибка: typedef
'PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC' is initialized (use decltype instead)
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC) (GLenum mode,
GLuint start, GLuint end, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const void
*indices);    
'GLenum' was not declared in this scope   
'GLuint' was not declared in this scope   
'GLsizei' was not declared in this scope   
'GLenum' was not declared in this scope    
expected primary-expression before 'const'  typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC) (GLenum
mode, GLuint start, GLuint end, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const void
*indices);   
typedef 'PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC' is initialized (use decltype instead)  typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC) (GLenum target,
GLint level, GLint internalformat, GLsizei width, GLsizei height,
GLsizei depth, GLint border, GLenum format, GLenum type, const void
*pixels);
```

И так далее до бесконечности, но на 8140 ошибке я обычно останавливаю сборку. :\
Помогите, пожалуйста!!!
Qt5 устанавливал онлайн-установкой - библиотеку и IDE. Лечил потом их:

```
$ apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev  
$ sudo aptitude install mesa-common-dev    
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libfontconfig1
```

-всё делал, всё, что нашёл близкое к моей проблеме (Точно по моей проблеме гугл ничего внятного не говорит)

ОС: Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 32bit

Видеокарта: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family 
Integrated Graphics Controller (Короче, никакая. Может, в ней дело?)

OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 (QtOpengl = Оpengl которая и раньше стояла на ноуте сама по себе, или это разные вещи? Как зависят версии qt и opengl? Qt4-5 вообще работает со старой версией opengl, или побрезгует?)

Qt version: 4.8.6 (Так говорит консоль, хотя я не уверен, и мне кажется, что проекты с Qt5 собираются. Я не нашёл, как явно указать с библиотеками какой версии проги должны собираться. Не подскажете?)

В настройках QTcreator автоопределённый комплект: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 32bit

QMake version: 2.01a

Обнаруженный компилятор: GCC

Обнаруженный отладчик: GDB

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Видеокарта не причём.
У вас не находит либу.
Инклуды нашлись.

Думаю **QtOpengl != Оpengl**. OpenGL совместим почти со всеми версиями. У вас не находит базовых определений так что версия тут не при чём.

В .pro должно быть `QT = core gui opengl` но `QT += opengl` тоже должен работать.

Используйте команду `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so` что бы проверить пакеты и найдите способ проверить собираеться ли прога с путями из вывода этой команды.

Попробуйте выполнить команду `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt4-opengl-dev`

Comment: Это с чего бы это? Процитированные сообщения об ошибках ясно говорят, что "либа" тут ни при чем вообще. До "либы" дело даже отдаленно не дошло. Код просто тупо не компилируется.

Comment: @AnT очень удобно сказать "тупо не компилируется". Я пытаюсь на известной инфе телепатировать. Если бы был подключён неизвестный инклуд то ругалось бы именно на это, а т.к. на инклуд не ругается значит он найден.

Comment: Если ошибка возникает на стадии компиляции, это означает что код не компилируется и до линкера и либы дело даже не доходит.  А то, что кем-то где-то "найден какой-то инклуд" не значит вообще ничего и к делу возможно вообще не относится.

Comment: @AnT компилятором найден. и вы правы что это не линкер. похоже на то что инклуды есть но они кривые тобишь в них нет GLenum, GLuint и т.д. Надо смотреть инклуд диры что бы понять что не так.